# Python 'while'/'or' Issue

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm creating a program in python that involves integers and i want a piece of code to work like this:

```
num = int(input("Select a number: "))
while num != (1 or 2 or 3):
    num = int(input("Select a number: "))
```

PLease can you give me the correct code for this, Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow isn't so much of a "make me this code" thing as a "how do I make my code better" thing; Can you show us what you've tried so far? At the very least, it gives us context and helps us know what you understand/don't understand, so our answers are more useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `in` here:

```
while number not in (1, 2, 3):
```

Answer (score 1):

For the part of asking for numbers check [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

For the while loop, you can check [while loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while).

Comment: The OP might be on Python 3, using `input()` correctly. And his while loop is OK, the condition isn't. So this answer is not really helpful.

Comment: It is simply out of date, Tim Pietzcker. The post has been changed since I wrote it ;). But I do accept that I should have put a link to the Python 3 versions of the manuals.